# Why marked duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my English Language & Usage Stack Exchange post: [What is it called to use random error as evidence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/556123/what-is-it-called-to-use-random-error-as-evidence)

Why was this ever marked duplicate? Why not just migrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sympathize with your dilemma, but  please note that our site is user-moderated for the most part. Your question on the main has a couple of issues.

1. It is unclear to the average user on EL&U. (hence the "incoherent" answers)
2. It is too localized for our site and probably not suitable.
3. 3K users cannot vote to migrate except to English Learners.SE , or EL&U meta.
4. Only diamond mods can  migrate Qs to sites other than those already cited

All of that takes time. Patience is recommended.

Comment: Your title invited the closure. I suggest that you re-title the Q and opt for re-open (difficult), or rephrase for a new  Q.

Comment: 'What is a word for deliberate dismissal of some facts?' seemed to be exactly what your title was trying to put across. Your body question was 'What is this called, when I only publish good [I'm reading this as 'favourable'] results ...?' Seems identical. Then there's the fact that 'cherry-picking' appears in both, attracting multiple votes. // From the accepted answer though, it appears that migration to the technical site is best. 'Cherry-picking' is standard English; 'p-value hacking' is not.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Was this comment intended for the OP? Looks like they deleted their comments, so I got pinged...